# Form entry for user customized sql query

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I am attempting to run a query that is filtered by a specific date based on user input, here is my SELECT statement:

```
SELECT 
  dispatch_1.site_id, 
  dispatch_1.status_1, 
  dispatch_1.created_on, 
FROM 
  fpscdb001_ws_001.dispatch_1 
WHERE 
  DATE(dispatch_1.eta) = CURRENT_DATE
```

How do I make it so that the date can be determined by the user rather than CURRENT_DATE?

Comment: You create a form with sends a POST request to your PHP script running the query. *And it is just that simple.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get date with html posted data to this php file by $_POST[] array. for exaple :

```
$date=$_POST["userDate"];
```

by assumption that value is :

```
'01-01-2012'
```

u must change your query to this :

```
$sql="SELECT 
  dispatch_1.site_id, 
  dispatch_1.status_1, 
  dispatch_1.created_on, 
FROM 
  fpscdb001_ws_001.dispatch_1 
WHERE 
  DATE(dispatch_1.eta) = $date";
```

Comment: Still running into a problem...  the html form submit leads to a page not working error message. 

$Date= $_POST["userDate"]
$table= $_POST["userTable"]

SELECT *
FROM 
  fpscdb001_ws_001.$table 
WHERE 
  DATE($table.created_on) = '$Date';